# Why JavaScript 'forEach' doesn't work in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, foreach

I'm coding a simple app, but it's not working. I don't know why.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
    <title>First Scren</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btns">
            <button class="btn">1</button>
            <button class="btn">2</button>
            <button class="btn">3</button>
            <button class="btn">4</button>
        </div>

        <div class="text"></div>

    </div> 
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

js:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

function onClickBtn() {
    text.innerHTML = 'Click!';
}

text.innerHTML = 'JS was load';

btn.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', onClickBtn);
});
```

}

The Javascript file is working, but after click on the button, the text doesn't change. AddEventListener is not working with the arrow function, probably Cordova not working with ES6 JavaScript.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist - and nodelist's have not always had a `.forEach` ... what you can try is `const btn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));`

Comment: it's not working. now the 'JS was load' label does not appear

Comment: well, don't do that then ... wow, didn't realise cordova was so ... ancient

Comment: probably the problem is not with cordova, but with android api. i was using the old api so it was using the old webview. Now I will check on new android

Comment: https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/should-you-transpile-your-cordova-app